# Запрос на выборку неодинаковых данных

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Добрый день. Имеется таблица `message` поля `(id, sender, receiver, text)`. Как выбрать сообщения пользователя, но чтобы отправитель перечислялся один раз

```
$sql = "SELECT sender FROM message WHERE reseiver=$_SESSINO[uid]";
```

Например, если один и тот же пользователь написал 3 сообщения, то это вернёт мне 3 сообщений. Но я хочу чтоб это считалось одним. Возможно ли это как-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT `sender` FROM `message` WHERE `reseiver`=\''.$_SESSION['uid'].'\' group by `sender`';
```